# error while building omnet++ veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am very new to omnet++ and I need to install Veins.
I  am following the tutorial on the website but I have some troubles.

I am running omnet 5.1.1 and veins 4.6 on windows 8.1, when I build veins i get the following error

```
make MODE=release all
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/omnet/omnetpp-5.1.1/samples/veins/src'
MSGC: veins/base/messages/AirFrame.msg
make[1]: *** [Makefile:190: veins/base/messages/AirFrame_m.h] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/omnet/omnetpp-5.1.1/samples/veins/src'
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed SUMO system-wide by using its installer. This will add libraries to your system path that conflict with the ones used when compiling OMNeT++ simulations.

Uninstalling SUMO and using the .zip version of SUMO instead (see the [Veins tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) for exact steps) should solve this.